# Summing by case aliases

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following case statements :-

```
 ,case   when tariff_name like 'S%'
         <snip>
  end as SC
  ,case   when tariff_name like 'S%'
         <snip>  
  end as UR
```

Is it possible to sum the results of these cases?

```
SC+UR
```

gives me "UR": invalid identifier

Comment: Where is the rest of the code? That is pretty important here.

Comment: I couldn't post the rest because it made my question too much code

Comment: Well without that I would say a) make two variables and set them to the values then add the two variables as the sum or b) use a cte and sum the columns that way

Comment: Not in Oracle. You can't use aliases in the same SELECT where they are defined. (There may be other database products where that will work, but not in Oracle.) You either need a subquery-outer query structure of some sort, or you will have to repeat the full formulas, with a plus sign between them, in the SELECT at the same level.

Comment: How did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you're summing these values not in the scope they are already defined, so try to build your query like:

```
select (SC + UR) as SUM1 from (select field1, 
       case when field2 like 'S%' 
         then '1'
       end as SC,
       case when field2 like 'L%' 
         then '2'
       end as UR 
from table1);
```

Another approach:

```
with temp as (
    select field1, 
           case when field2 like 'S%' 
             then '1'
           end as SC,
           case when field2 like 'L%' 
             then '2'
           end as UR 
    from table1)
select (t.SC + t.UR) as SUM1 from temp t;
```

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible to sum them if you do something like below

;with cte as (
select * ,case   when tariff_name like 'S%'
         
  end as SC
  ,case   when tariff_name like 'S%'
         
  end as UR

from SomeTable

)

select *,SC+UR as [sum]

from cte